# In VSCode how to navigate to the begin or the end of a expression?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Suppose I have entered a long chain call

```js
f()
    .g()
    .h()
```

and my cursor is at the end of `.h()`.

Now I want to `await` this expression and create a const for it.

So I want to **navigate to the begin** of this chain-calling expression, which is before `f()`.

Then I enter `const v = await` , so the whole code become

```js
const v = await f()
    .g()
    .h()
```

Then I need to continue writing. I want to **navigate to the end** of this chain expression, which is after `.h()`.

My question is, is there any quick way to do this navigation.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: TypeScript. I want a general solution if possible though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I found an extension for it

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ipatalas.vscode-postfix-ts